# Why does my editable input fields submit empty strings if I edit only one of the input fields?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, ckeditor4.x

I'm trying to create a very simple Content Management System for creating and updating blog posts. I managed to successfully create and delete blog posts but I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around when I try to edit them.

The problem I'm running into is if I have 3 fields that are Editable for the Blog Post.

1) Blog Topic
2) Blog Picture
3) Blog Content

If I edit 1 field such as `Blog Topic` with test data and I submit the changes, the data that was in Blog Picture and Blog Content get lost and submit nothing even though there was data there previously and I'm not sure why. However, if I set the `defaultValue` to my state whenever I save to make changes, the problem gets fixed but I want my inputs to have the initial value in there field also.

Here is my code:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Header from "../common/Header";
import Footer from "../common/Footer";
import Adminediting from "../common/isEditing";
import Addblogtopic from "./Addblogtopic";

import { Modal, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Moment from "moment";
import dataTip from "data-tip";
import { confirmAlert } from "react-confirm-alert";
import CKEditor from "ckeditor4-react";

import blogtopicsService from "../../services/Blogservice";
import appController from "../../controllers/appController";

class Blogtopics extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: false,
      blogData: [],
      blogCategory: "",
      blogContent: "",
      blogId: "",
      hoverSelected: false,
      isEditing: false,
      fileObject: "",
      fileName: "",
      fileSize: "",
      fileType: "",
      filePayload: "",
      blogPicture: "",
      email: "",
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      roleId: "",
      userId: "",
      errorMsg2: false,
      errorMsg3: false
    };
  }

  Selectblogtopics = async () => {
    const blogTopics = await blogtopicsService.selectblogTopics();

    this.setState({
      blogData: blogTopics
    });
  };

  toggleHover = hoverState => {
    this.setState({ hoverSelected: hoverState });
  };

  updateImage = e => {
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    var dataTypeURL = new FileReader();
    var arrayBuffer = new FileReader();
    this.setState({
      fileObject: file,
      fileName: file.name,
      fileSize: file.size,
      fileType: file.type
    });

    dataTypeURL.onload = e => {
      this.setState({
        filePayload: e.target.result,
        blogPicture: e.target.result
      });
    };
    dataTypeURL.readAsDataURL(file);
    arrayBuffer.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  };

  editBlog = editingState => {
    this.setState({
      isEditing: !editingState
    });

      //Publish Changes
      setTimeout(async () => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false
        });

        const uploadData = {
          blogCategory: this.state.blogCategory,
          blogContent: this.state.blogContent,
          modifiedDate: Moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"),
          blogId: this.state.blogId,
          fileType: this.state.fileType,
          fileName: this.state.fileName,
          fileSize: this.state.fileSize,
          filePayload: this.state.filePayload
        };

        const updateBlog = await blogtopicsService.editBlog(uploadData);

        location.href = "/blog";
      }, 1000);
    }
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ show: false });
  };

  handleShow = () => {
    this.setState({ show: true });
  };

  onChange = async (e, blogId) => {
    await this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      blogId: blogId
    });
  };

  deleteBlog = blogId => {
    confirmAlert({
      customUI: ({ onClose }) => {
        return (
          <div className="custom-ui">
            <h1>Are you sure</h1>
            <p>You want to delete this blog?</p>
            <button onClick={onClose}>Cancel</button>
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                this.confirmDelete(blogId);
                onClose();
              }}
            >
              Confirm
            </button>
          </div>
        );
      }
    });
  };

  confirmDelete = async blogId => {
    // Delete the blog
    const deleteBlog = await blogtopicsService.deleteBlog({ blog_id: blogId });

    // Re-render the blog posts after deleting
    await this.Selectblogtopics();
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.userData();
    await this.Selectblogtopics();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="fluid-container">
        <div className="blogContainer">
          <Header />
            <Adminediting
              title={this.props.match.path}
              editState={this.editBlog}
            />
          <div className="container">
              <div className="editSection">
                <div className="text-right">
                  <span className="data-tip-bottom" data-tip="Add Blog Post">
                    <i className="fas fa-plus" onClick={this.handleShow} />
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            <div className="blogContent">
              {this.state.blogData.map((rows, index) => (
                <div className="blogWrapper" key={index}>
                  {rows.blog_status === 1 ? (
                    <div
                      className="row"
                    >
                      <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose}>
                        <Modal.Header closeButton>
                          <Modal.Title>Add Blog Post</Modal.Title>
                        </Modal.Header>
                        <Modal.Body>
                          <Addblogtopic
                            handleClose={this.handleClose}
                            selectblogTopics={this.Selectblogtopics}
                          />
                        </Modal.Body>
                      </Modal>
                      <div className="col-md-4">
                        <img
                          src={
                            "https://s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/" +
                            rows.blog_thumbnail
                          }
                          alt="test"
                        />
                        {this.state.isEditing === true ? (
                          <div className="input-group">
                            <input
                              type="file"
                              className="d-block mt-4"
                              name="blogPicture"
                              onChange={e => this.updateImage(e)}
                            />
                          </div>
                        ) : null}
                      </div>
                      <div className="col-md-6">
                        {this.state.isEditing === true ? (
                          <input
                            type="text"
                            name="blogCategory"
                            onChange={e => this.onChange(e, rows.blog_id)}
                            defaultValue={rows.blog_category}
                          />
                        ) : (
                          <Link
                            to={
                              "/blog/" +
                              rows.blog_id +
                              "/" +
                              appController.friendlyUrl(rows.blog_category)
                            }
                            id="blogUrl"
                          >
                            <h3
                              id="blogTopic"
                              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                                __html: rows.blog_category
                              }}
                            />
                          </Link>
                        )}
                        {this.state.roleId === 1 ? (
                          <div className="editSection">
                            <div className="text-right">
                              <span
                                className="data-tip-bottom"
                                data-tip="Delete Blog Post"
                              >
                                <i
                                  className="far fa-trash-alt"
                                  onClick={e => this.deleteBlog(rows.blog_id)}
                                />
                              </span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        ) : null}

                        <div
                          className={
                            this.state.hoverSelected == index
                              ? "blogSection hover"
                              : "blogSection"
                          }
                        >
                          {this.state.isEditing === true ? (
                            <CKEditor
                              data={rows.blog_content}
                              onChange={(event, editor) => {
                                const data = event.editor.getData();
                                this.setState({
                                  blogContent: data
                                });
                              }}
                            />
                          ) : rows.blog_content.length > 50 ? (
                            <div
                              className="cmsStyles"
                              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                                __html: rows.blog_content.substr(0, 50) + " ..."
                              }}
                            />
                          ) : (
                            <div
                              className="cmsStyles"
                              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                                __html: rows.blog_content
                              }}
                            />
                          )}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  ) : null}
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Blogtopics;
```

**Back End Data**

```js
var db = require("../dbconnection");
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

var blog = {
  insertblogPost: function(data, callback) {
    var uniquePicture = "blogphoto" + "-" + data.fileName;
    var awsFolder = "awsfolder" + "/" + uniquePicture;
    db.query(
      "insert blog_topics set blog_category=?, blog_thumbnail=?, blog_content=?, blog_author=?",
      [data.blogTopic, uniquePicture, data.blogContent, "random user"]
    );

    var buf = new Buffer(
      data.filePayload.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""),
      "base64"
    );

    //Upload file into AWS S3 Bucket
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    var params = {
      Bucket: "testbucket",
      Key: awsFolder,
      Body: buf,
      ContentType: data.fileType,
      ACL: "public-read"
    };
    s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
      } else {
        return data;
      }
    }),
      callback(true);
  },
  deleteBlog: function(data, callback) {
    db.query(
      "UPDATE blog_topics set blog_status=? where blog_id=?",
      ["0", data.blog_id],
      callback
    );
  },
  editBlog: function(data, callback) {
    var uniquePicture = "blogphoto" + "-" + data.fileName;
    var awsFolder = "awsfolder" + "/" + uniquePicture;
    db.query(
      "UPDATE blog_topics set blog_category=?, blog_thumbnail=?, blog_content=?, blog_author=?, modified_date=? where blog_id=?",
      [
        data.blogCategory,
        uniquePicture,
        data.blogContent,
        "Test Username",
        data.modifiedDate,
        data.blogId
      ]
    );

    var buf = new Buffer(
      data.filePayload.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""),
      "base64"
    );

    //Upload file into AWS S3 Bucket
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    var params = {
      Bucket: "awsbucket",
      Key: awsFolder,
      Body: buf,
      ContentType: data.fileType,
      ACL: "public-read"
    };
    s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
      } else {
        return data;
        //console.log(data);
      }
    }),
      callback(true);
  },
  selectblogTopics: function(data, callback) {
    db.query(
      "select blog_id, blog_category, blog_thumbnail, blog_content, blog_status, blog_author, created_date, modified_date from blog_topics",
      callback
    );
  },
  selectblogArticle: function(data, callback) {
    db.query(
      "select blog_id, blog_category, blog_thumbnail, blog_content, blog_author, created_date from blog_topics where blog_id=?",
      [data.blogId],
      callback
    );
  },
  editArticle: function(data, callback) {
    var uniquePicture = "blogphoto" + "-" + data.fileName;
    var awsFolder = "awsfolder" + "/" + uniquePicture;
    db.query(
      "UPDATE blog_topics set blog_category=?, blog_thumbnail=?, blog_content=?, blog_author=?, modified_date=? where blog_id=?",
      [
        data.blogCategory,
        uniquePicture,
        data.blogContent,
        "test user",
        data.modifiedDate,
        data.blogId
      ]
    );

    var buf = new Buffer(
      data.filePayload.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""),
      "base64"
    );

    //Upload file into AWS S3 Bucket
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    var params = {
      Bucket: "awsfolder",
      Key: awsFolder,
      Body: buf,
      ContentType: data.fileType,
      ACL: "public-read"
    };
    s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
      } else {
        return data;
      }
    }),
      callback(true);
  }
};

module.exports = blog;
```

Comment: I think my problem is very simple. I think it has to do with my misunderstanding of controlled vs uncontrolled inputs. Basically, whenever I put `defaultValue` on any of my inputs and set its value equal to `row.blog_content` instead of `this.state.blogContent` it submits the other fields as empty whenever I submit changes. However, if I change the value to the state it solves my problem but when I open my editor I no longer have the default value in the field. It's difficult to replicate the issue cause it's a full stack application. Is it possible I can send you video or something?

Comment: At least you have to add the input fields and how you are using it, there's no input in your question. You can add the input fields to reproduce the stackblitz, if you can't reproduce it in a minimal stackblitz, may be the problem is elsewhere. How can we be sure?

Comment: Ok I created the stack Blits you requested please see example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mulg2x When you click on "Edit me" It init editor, I want to be able to load blogCategory, blogContent immediately into state after I click the edit button. However, it's not going into state only after I hit "publish" to make changes. Also in this example I had to hardcode the blogData because in my real app, I'm fetching the data from the db so in the real app blogData is actually an empty string to start off and then I'm putting it into state later on.

Comment: There isn't a 'save option for me' I see 'Fork' and 'Share' only?

Comment: You have to fork, you may need to login/create account for that too, <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd> does save/fork it too I guess.

Comment: Here is my own link is this okay? https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sqmtph I also put the comment in the blogTopic file indicating the issue I'm currently stuck on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196781/discussion-between-munim-munna-and-jorden).

Comment: I got it thank you very much. I would like to reward you the bounty @Munim Munna. Can you post an answer so I can award bounty. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a generic method to update all blog info.

```
setBlogProperty(index, propName, propValue) {
  this.setState(state => {
    state.blogData[index][propName] = propValue;
    return state;
  });
};
```

Then call this method on `onChange` event of your input element.

```
<input
  type="text"
  name="blogCategory"
  onChange={e => this.setBlogProperty(index, 'blog_category', e.target.value)}
  defaultValue={rows.blog_category}
/>
```